# Java Search In 2D Array using arrayName[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase not finding value

Tags: java, android, arrays, 2d

I've been searching the community for the past few hours looking for a solution. If you find this as a duplicate please close and direct me to the solution. Thanks in advance!

I'm searching through a 2D array looking to match a card combination entered in a TextView with a card combination in the array. Code is not recognizing that it has found the correct entry and always loops through as False. I'm wondering if I'm not storing and searching for the string in the correct way.

For example, if in the TextView I entered Q3 the Logcat will show:

Checking:: [Q3]
Searching:: [Q3]

So I know we're looping through and hitting the correct item in the Array. But I cannot get the code to recognize it.

```
//Get the text from the holeCards TextView
holeCards = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enter_cards_text);
String holeCardsText = ((TextView) holeCards).getText().toString();

//Search cardParisArray for holeCardsText

int rows = cardPairsArray.length;
int columns = cardPairsArray[0].length;
String cardPairArrayRows = Integer.toString(rows);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

        Log.d("Searching:", Arrays.toString(new String[]{holeCardsText}));
        Log.d("Checking:", Arrays.toString(new String[]{cardPairsArray[i][j]}));

        if (cardPairsArray[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(holeCardsText) == true) {

            responseTextView.setText("Cards were found");

        }else responseTextView.setText("Cards not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting a String to a String[] and then back to a String for your Log?

Comment: The `else` case makes no sense here. You basically setting the value of `responseTextView` in every iteration. This means, even if you find what are you looking for in the array, the `responseTextView` most likely will be overwritten.

Comment: Just put the "Cards not found" before the loop and remove the else case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was twofold. Else statement was overriding when the string was found. So I removed the else statement.

Second contains requires case to match so I ensured that text entered in the Text View is converted to capital.

Please feel free to comment if you have a better answer.